# Why we get ENOLOCAL in ReactNative

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

i have created a fresh new React native application, however if i try to run the app using `npx react-native run-android` i'm getting the error.

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\15180" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ramesh PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-09T09_22_11_453Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'react-native@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

Why we receive this error?.

Comment: Please note, its valid question, FYI...

Answer (score 1):

Its really annoying by seeing the people are giving -ve vote for my question without proper reason.

it may be useful for someone who is really facing the issue

follow below steps

```
you can change "npm-cache" folder to anothor path,
using command :
"npm config set cache C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache --global"
```

This will resolve the issue.

More info https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/146

Comment: thanks. I was so confused on the error since I was getting error on powershell but not on wsl.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot to solve this almost spend 2 hr in mine case i was not allow to delete package-lock.json

uninstall node

```
brew uninstall node; 
# or `brew uninstall --force node` which removes all versions
brew cleanup;
rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d;
rm -rf ~/.npm;
```

install again

```
brew install node;
which node # => /usr/local/bin/node
export NODE_PATH='/usr/local/lib/node_modules' # <--- add this ~/.bashrc
```